# Add X in to first line in internally table

Tags: abap

Any idea how to add X into zcheck_par always in first line in internally table for the diffrent workcenter?
i have internally table with result like:

plant workcenter zcheck_par

4110  P-1

4110  P-1

4110  P-2

4110  P-2

4110  P-2

4110  P-3

4110  P-3

4110  P-4

4110  P-4

4110  P-4

4110  P-4

Expectation:

4110  P-1   X

4110  P-1

4110  P-2   X

4110  P-2

4110  P-2

4110  P-3   X

4110  P-3

4110  P-4   X

4110  P-4

4110  P-4

4110  P-4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AT-Statements

```
LOOP AT workcenters INTO DATA(workcenter).
  AT NEW workcenter.
    workcenter-zcheck_par = 'X'.
  ENDAT.
  INSERT workcenter INTO TABLE workcenters_output.
ENDLOOP.
```

The internal table `workcenters_output` contains the expected output. It's a new table to prevent syntax warning. In LOOPs with AT statements, the table shouldn't be modified.